# How to write a sql query to find a word in a para?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
("select * from table where column like ?", ['%' + var1 + '%'])
```

shows results like "cabcd a", "xyabcd xyz", " xyz abc", "x abc","abc y".  But i only want the output to be like "xyz abc", "x abc", "abc y".  And abc is stored in  var1

Comment: Then your pattern should include a space in front of abc.

Comment: what if abc is stored in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
where concat(' ', column, ' ') like "% abc %"
```

This will find the word anywhere in the column, assuming the only valid separator is a space.

Note:  In SQLite, you would use `||` instead of `concat()`.  Also, if you want performance, look into full text indexes.

EDIT:

The code if the value is stored in a variable looks like:

```
"select * from table where concat(' ', column, ' ') like ?", ['% ' + var1 + ' %'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp1
WHERE name LIKE '% abc%'
OR name LIKE 'abc_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about searching with spaces on either side:

```
select * from table where column like "% abc%" or  column like "%abc %"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE column LIKE "% abc%" OR column LIKE "%abc %" OR column="abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your String is saved in a variable try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column LIKE CONCAT('% ', var1, '%') OR column LIKE CONCAT(var1,' %'));
```

Extra parentheses are to avoid confusion if you add more constraints (AND operators have precedence over OR).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP` and the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word-boundary markers:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP "[[:<:]]abc[[:>:]]";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the variable

```
DECLARE @Pattern_Val AS CHAR(7)
SET @Pattern_Val = '% abc %'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE @Pattern_Val
```

CAUTION: Pay attention to the length of the CHAR - Definition!!